# Nullable Expressions

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I have this method

```
public Sorting(Expression<Func<T, object>> property, bool ascending = true)
```

and I want to be able to call it something like this

```
public Sorting(null)
```

By this I mean I want to specify no expression and use the default value for `ascending`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Passing `null` to method smells...

Comment: What's the best way to do this then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need to specify expression, then create overload for this constructor (I think  its constructor, not simple method) which don't have expression parameter (instead of passing null):

```
public Sorting(Expression<Func<T, object>> property, bool ascending = true)
public Sorting(bool ascending = true)
```

Side note - I also don't like passing boolean values to methods, because they are not expressive and its hard to understand what they mean:

```
Sorting(false) // what is that?
```

Usually I create different methods instead (like `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`) or pass some enumeration (like `Order.Ascending` and `Order.Descending`). With constructors you cannot specify custom name, so I use static creation methods for that. That is much easier to read:

```
Sorting.CreateDescendingSorting()
Sorting(Order.Ascending)
```

Comment: _I also don't like passing boolean values to methods_ then use named arguments :)) `Sorting(ascending: false)`

Comment: Using named arguments when passing boolean literals makes the code *so* much more readable.  I've even started doing it with comments when I write Java code, e.g., `Sorting(/*ascending:*/false)`.